# Use waf to link boost on ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, boost, waf

I'm using waf to build a C++ project on ubuntu 13.10. I try conf.load(boost) in configuration function in wscript, but the result shows it cannot find boost in /lib64. I use apt-get to install libboost. It was installed on /usr/lib/x86_64-gnu-linux. It seems that waf cannot automatically search this directory. How to specify the location when load or check a library in waf.

Answer (score 0):

Use `waf --help` and you will see that there is a `--boost-libs` option. Invoke:

```
./waf configure --boost-libs=/lib64
```

This should do the correct thing if I didn't misunderstand you.